# How can I set the bottom-to-top-link button for my ListView in Android?

Tags: android, listview, bottom-up

I want to create a bottom-to-top-link button in Andorid. I have a ListView with a large amount of data.

For an example have a look at [this website](http://www.clitetechnologies.com/). Imagine you scrolled down to the bottom of the webpage and you want to get back to the top of the webpage.  To do that, you can click the back-to-top button that is scrolling the page back to the beginning of the document.

In the same way I want that for my ListView in Android. I have searched in Google but I didn't find anything related to that. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

there are several ways to scroll to top of your list

```
listView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();

listView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);

listview.setSelection(0);
```

Comment: What if i use linearlayout inside scrollview. How can i set?

Answer (score 0):

```
myFAB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myScrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged - consider adding a bit of explanation.